# I want to supply under 1.1V to xilinx virtex5 Vccint how to make the volatage?

Tags: power, xilinx, ldo

I'd like to supply under 1.1v to xilinx Virtex5 Vccint.
The input voltage is 5.
But I can't find any reference how to make like under 1.1v.
Does anyone know how to make it,  please give to me any hint.

Comment: This is a full power supply design. Check with Xilinx's reference design(s) for the Virtex 5. You are looking for a high-current, switching buck regulator design.

Comment: The Virtex V is a pretty power hungry device, you're going to need some serious DC-DC converters, having said that, there are plenty of fully integrated units (like the one Mario suggested, but there are plenty of others) where all you have to add is two feedback resistors (which set the output voltage) and lots and lots of ceramic bypass capacitors (ideally some big beefy ones close to the DC-DC and lots of small ones right under the FPGA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to check the reference designs.

A typically solution would be to use a step-down converter as shown below
[image]

The output voltage can be set by resistor R195. With this specific regulator the lowest possible voltage is around 0.65V.

For details you can check the datasheet of the PTH08T220W